# Certain content won't display in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm in the process of creating a website.

This website works great in Chrome (10), FF (3.6.13), however only *half* of it works in IE (8). Now, I'm aware of some of the issues between browsers,  but this one has me stumped. Because *half* of the script is working (displaying properly) -- the other half does not.

A live version of the website may be found [here](http://projektnull.com/pages/home.html)

Additional information:

I am using the html5 doctype, `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I have validated my site with HTML5 as well as HTML4.01 STRICT

**EDIT**

At the request of Zabba, here is what SHOULD be happening:

I am externally loading content from other sources into my website.
My menu(s) and the text. In Chrome, and FF the menus, and the content are loaded and displayed. In IE, the menus are NOT loaded bu the content is. Funny enough, the logo also stops loading in IE.

**EDIT**

The problem has been narrowed down to a CSS issue, thank you!

Comment: Which half of script is not working for you? Left half or right half? Is the script working for someone else?

Comment: @Zabba That's very bizarre. I'm using FF3.6.13, and it displays just fine. Do you think you could take a screenshot of it for me?

Comment: @Johannes, my first comment was a humorous attempt to get you to give more detail about "what is not working", "what is the problem" etc. :)

Comment: I have checked that the jQuery.load doesn't work, but I don't know why.

Comment: Try disabling your CSS entirely, and see if the text from the missing pieces shows up at all. If it does, the the problem is in your CSS and not in your JS.

Comment: @Zabba. Edited with more detail.

Comment: @Billy: I would think so too, however SOME of the content loads.

Comment: @Mark Eirich: I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm looking at IE7, and I see that your logo does not show up at all. The logo is static and isn't loaded via JavaScript. This points to a CSS issue.

Comment: Yes, it's a CSS issue. I can see it in IE now, Johannes (after you removed CSS).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. I'll play around with it.

Comment: Try putting the content_text div AFTER the allMenus div

Comment: Try setting z-index:6 on the missing items. I see that #body has z-index:5. IE sometimes is weird about that.

Comment: I'm looking in IE8 and it seems to be working. Was this fixed?

Comment: @Mark Eirich: Could you just submit these as an answer? I'll be more than happy to accept it, as CSS is where all my problems lie.

Comment: @Corey Sunwold: I'm doing a lot of editing on my website right now, you'll see it jumping around quite a bit.

Comment: @Johannes: home.html and home2.html look identical to me in IE7 (both broken). Please try clearing your browser cache, and possibly re-starting the browser.

Comment: @Mark Eirich See, I thought that might be the issue. But, after clearing my cache, it came out the same. -- Yet I seem to be the only one with this issue. I'll reboot,

Comment: I'm now thinking this may have to do with the fact that the missing items are positioned OUTSIDE of their container....

Comment: I think so too. But I'm not quite sure how I'd position them as I'd like without doing it how I already am... after my reboot IE9 installed (which is what was causing my issues) and it looks great in IE9. But now I don't know how to fix it in IE8..

Comment: @Johannes: again, did you try removing the `filter` property from the #body style block? That seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your CSS, not your JavaScript. Try these suggestions:

Remove your `filter:alpha(opacity=80)` from the #body block in your CSS.

Set z-index values of >5 on the missing items, since you have z-index:5 on #body. Or remove the z-index from #body.

Comment: @Mark Eirich please review my question again, I completely changed it. And please see if you can confirm my findings.

Comment: @Johannes: page.html and page2.html look identical to me, and both broken; did you get a chance to try removing the filter:alpha yet?

Comment: Edit | Actually, nevermind, I think that did fix it. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Johannes: Welcome to Internet Explorer. :-S If you do still need to fade the background, just do it in your photo editor.

Comment: @Mark Eirich Thank you so much for all of your help! It is more than appreciated!